# Python and Snowflake how can add Azure AD username and password to snowflake connection to be able to access the account and run ETL scripts?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to login to Snowflake through our Azure AD integration button.

My connection script was using the credentials of a trial account where there is only the username and password on snowflake:

```
conn = snowCtx.connect(
    user=user,
    password=password,
    account=account,
    database=database,
    schema=schema,
    warehouse=warehouse,
    role='SYSADMIN',
    autocommit=False,
)
```

Now I need to add and integrate the Azure AD username and password with the connection on order to access my prod account and start my ETL process.

I checked the [following](https://medium.com/@qiuyujx/azure-functions-connect-to-snowflake-a-simple-test-of-the-snowflake-connector-python-133a0c90c585):

```
import azure.functions as func
```

but before that I installed the azure library using:

```
pip install azure
```

But there is no module `functions` within `azure` library.

How can I add the Azure AD authentication to snowflake cursor?

Comment: For your question about `But there is no module functions within azure library`, `azure.functions` is a module which already installed when you created the python function in VS code. So do not need to care about it.

Comment: If your question is resolved, please accept the answer so it gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pip install azure-functions` to install `azure.functions`.

Also see [Quickstart: Create a Python function in Azure from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python), [Azure Functions Python developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python) and [Improve throughput performance of Python apps in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/python-scale-performance-reference).

> But there is no module `functions` within `azure` library.

From https://pypi.org/project/azure/:

> Starting with v5.0.0, **this package is deprecated**. Please install the service specific packages prefixed by azure needed for your application.